# How Two Different Domain Name Are Going To Use Same Content?

Tags: php, url, dns

Recently I am so concerning about my site, because anyone stole my site contents, and using them by his domain name .

This is my site or domain name http://www.clippingpathspecialist.com, and This is his http://dramaqueenweddingshow.com

You see the same content is showing different two domain name. How does he do that, and Why ? Is there any question about my site ?

Please give me a suggestion to remove my concern

Thanks in advance

Bijutoha

Comment: Happens to all of us, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=clippingpathspecialist.com & http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=dramaqueenweddingshow.com, both near the end at the WWW section, both domains are pointing to the same IP 198.57.187.81

Comment: Thanks for the good informative suggestion, So now what should I do ? Please explain something ...

Comment: at a guess, given that the dramaqueenweddingshow.com domain does not appear to be related to your business, I'd say this is a mistake rather than someone stealing your content on purpose. I would contact my hosting provider or the owner of that domain as seen here http://centralops.net/co/DomainDossier.aspx?addr=dramaqueenweddingshow.com&dom_dns=1&dom_whois=1&net_whois=1

Answer (score 0):

I think another site has cloned / mirrored you site and displaying it. there are several methods it can be preventd, try this 'robot.txt' for more check below

[CLICK HERE](http://www.techiezone.net/tutorials/tips-tricks/use-robots-txt-to-prevent-website-from-being-ripped/) or

simple one
In Apache, set up virtual hosting. You can disallow access to your site from anyother domain.

Answer (score 0):

Simply they configured the domain name (the A record in DNS) to point to your server IP Address. You can avoid this in many ways. Try to ping the two and you'll get the same IP!
The best way is to check the http header and if not match your site give a 404 response.

Comment: Thanks for the good informative suggestion, One important thing is I got every mail from his domain yet. So what is the benefit of him ?